# In a WP7 application, is there a way to access files stored using phone as mass storage device

Tags: windows-phone-7

If I store data on a Windows Phone 7, is there a way to access the files that are stored that way in an an application?

More specifically this application needs to perform some processing on data that is stored using the phone as mass storage device.

Comment: I don't believe a WP7 device can be put into mass storage mode, unless you're talking about custom ROMs/homebrew.

Comment: If you want to access the isolated file system of windows phone application, please download the application from below link and try (i got this link from Microsoft website only and it wont work with XP machine).

http://download-codeplex.sec.s-msft.com/Download/SourceControlFileDownload.ashx?ProjectName=isostorespy&changeSetId=19567

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have direct access to the file system, so it isn't possible to read those files from an application.

Comment: Does this also mean that it would not be possible to read data that would be written by a different app?

Comment: Yes. Apart from the data stored by your app, you can only access some specific data on the phone (like pictures and contacts) by using tasks